# Version of (damped) Newton-method

Tags: convergence-divergence, newton-raphson

Show that there is no $\lambda \in (0,1]$ so that
$$ x_{k+1}=x_k-\lambda\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}$$

is global convergent.

I know that Newton ($\lambda =1)$ isn't global convergent for $f(x)= arctan(x)$, my idea was to construct a function $f(x,\lambda)$ so that the above method isn't global convergent. But I dont find any.

Greetings.

Comment: Do you mean that there is no $\lambda \in (0, 1]$ such that the iteration scheme $x_{k + 1} = x_k - \lambda (f(x_k) / f'(x_k))$ converges for *all* functions $f$, no matter what value $x_0$ may take?

Comment: I guess I'm trying to as just what is meant here by *global convergence*?

Comment: Of  course not, for linear functions, newton is global convergent. Rather, there exists $f \in C^1 $ where newton isnt global convergent.

Comment: global convergence: for all starting values in $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ the method produces a sequence $x_k$ with $f(x_k) \to 0,~k \to \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way of constructing a non-convergent sequence is to try to construct a *cycle* where the iteration just goes back and forth without converging. Take for example $f(x) = ax^3 + bx + c$ with $a,b,c\not=0$ (simplest polynomial where this can happen) and start with $x_0 = 0$ and compute $x_1$ and $x_2$ and enforce $x_2 = 0$. This will give you an (over-determined) equation system for $a,b,c$ so just pick some values that satisfy it and double-check that $x_1$ is not a root and you have your counter-example. For example if $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$ then $f(x) = 3x^3 - 5x - 10$ works as $x_0 = 0$ gives  $x_1 = -1$ and $x_2 = 0$.